# Sending multiple POST Req in a forEach loop React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, foreach

In the code below I put a post REQ function inside a forEach loop and send a req for every selectedService entry that exists within that array. Then when the loop finished I fetch all the userServices and set that to my state.

```
  const handleAddServiceToUser = async () => {
    if (selectedServices === []) {
      setErr('Please Select A Service')
    } else {

      selectedServices.forEach(async (selectedService) => {
        await addNewUserService(userId, selectedService.id)
      })
      const res = await getUserServicesList(userId)
      setUserServices(res.data)

      handleClose()
      if (err !== '') {
        setErr('')
      }
      setSelectedServices([])
    }
  }
```

I have never seen or tried anything like this before (async forEach). The code does seem to be working when I test it in my client. I am assuming it is probably not a best practice to do something like this? Is this acceptable in terms of performance? And if not what is an alternative?

Comment: Unless these need to run sequentially you should `await Promise.all(services.map(s => addNewUserService(userId, s.id)))`.

Comment: @rayhatfield Nice!